# Where should I redirect users from deleted pages?

Tags: 404

A site I work on has a lot of 404 errors. Right now a 404 page is displayed. I want to do a 301 redirect for such posts. Where should I redirect the pages to?

Answer (score 1):

You should only redirect if you have a similar page - if you don't have a similar page you should just let them 404. If you redirect to a non-related page Google will consider it as a soft 404.
You should however update all internal links to these pages - a tool like Screaming Frog will help you identify the pages with the bad links.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the pages are i'd suggest a 301 redirect to the next level of the IA or to the next most relevant page.